# Flutter Best way to Pass data from a class to a widget variable

Tags: flutter, dart, speech-to-text

I'm working with the **Speech_to_text package** to store the voice recognition result in a string variable that I can use later for different purposes, So far I just want to show the String on screen. I want to achieve a functionality similar to Whatsaap recording so I have `GestureDetector` with the `onLongPress` starting the recording and `onLongPressUp` stopping it.

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  
  //Variable to show on screen
  String text = 'Press the button and start speaking';
  
  bool isListening = false;

  final SpeechToText speech = SpeechToText();

  String lastError = "";
  String lastStatus = "";
  String _currentLocaleId = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initSpeechState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(MyApp.title),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          reverse: true,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30).copyWith(bottom: 150),
          child: SubstringHighlight(
            text: text,
            terms: Command.all,
            textStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 32.0,
              color: Colors.black,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
            textStyleHighlight: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 32.0,
              color: Colors.red,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
        floatingActionButton: AvatarGlow(
          animate: isListening,
          endRadius: 75,
          glowColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          child: GestureDetector(
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(isListening ? Icons.mic : Icons.mic_none, size: 36),
              /*onPressed: () {
                toggleRecording();
                print(text);
              }*/
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            onLongPress: () {
              setState(() async {
                text = await Speech.startListening();
              });

              // print(text);
            },
            onLongPressUp: Speech.stopListening,

            //sendMessage(),
          ),
        ),
      );

  Future<void> initSpeechState() async {
    bool hasSpeech = await speech.initialize(
        onError: errorListener, onStatus: statusListener, debugLogging: false);
  }

  //Speech to text methods
  Future<void> errorListener(SpeechRecognitionError error) async {
    print("Received error status: $error, listening: ${speech.isListening}");
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        lastError = "${error.errorMsg} - ${error.permanent}";
        print(lastError);
      });
    }
  }

  void statusListener(String status) {
    setState(() {
      print(status);
      lastStatus = "$status";
    });
  }
}
```

Both `OnLongPress` and `OnLongPressUp` calls the methods `startListening` and `stopListening`, respectively, that are in a different class.

```
class Speech {
  static final _speech = SpeechToText();
  static String lastWords;


  void cancelListening() {
    _speech.cancel();
  }

  static Future startListening() async {
    await _speech.listen(
        onResult: resultListener,
        listenFor: Duration(minutes: 1),
        cancelOnError: true,
        partialResults: false);
    return lastWords;
  }

  static void stopListening() {
    _speech.stop();
    
  }

  static resultListener(SpeechRecognitionResult result) {
    lastWords = "${result.recognizedWords}";
    //print(lastWords);
    if (lastWords != '') {
      //this is what I want to pass to the Text variable on the Main Widget
      print(lastWords);
    }
  }
}
```

I thought that I just needed assign the `startListening` method to the Text variable in the main widget

```
 onLongPress: () {
              setState(() async {
                text = await Speech.startListening();
              });
```

given the `athe` method is returning the string needed

```
 static Future startListening() async {
    await _speech.listen(
        onResult: resultListener,
        listenFor: Duration(minutes: 1),
        cancelOnError: true,
        partialResults: false);
    return lastWords;
  }
```

but that approach resulted in a redScreen error:

> ════════ Exception caught by gesture
> ═══════════════════════════════════════════ The following assertion
> was thrown while handling a gesture: setState() callback argument
> returned a Future.
>
> The setState() method on _HomePageState#0ff8a was called with a
> closure or method that returned a Future. Maybe it is marked as
> "async".
>
> Instead of performing asynchronous work inside a call to setState(),
> first execute the work (without updating the widget state), and then
> synchronously update the state inside a call to setState().
>
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
> #0      State.setState. package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:1270
> #1      State.setState package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:1286
> #2      _HomePageState.build. lib\page\home_page.dart:75
> #3      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:182
> #4      LongPressGestureRecognizer._checkLongPressStart package:flutter/…/gestures/long_press.dart:423 ... Handler:
> "onLongPress" Recognizer: LongPressGestureRecognizer#ac97b
> debugOwner: GestureDetector
> state: possible ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> I/flutter (11164): listening
>
> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library
> ═══════════════════════════════════ The method 'toLowerCase' was
> called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: toLowerCase() The
> relevant error-causing widget was SubstringHighlight
> lib\page\home_page.dart:45
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

, so I was thinking I could use the `resultListener`, that only gets called when there is a `voicerecognition` result, to send the `lastwords` string to the text variable in the main Widget, but I haven't figured out how.

P.D.
Having All the methods on the main Widget works but Im trying to implement clean Architecture so I want to keep that logic separated from the Ui widget.

Thanks.

//-------- Update -----------------

I kept researching and found a way to make it work using streams,

I created a stream controller in the Speech class, and then add a sink in the result listener.

```
static resultListener(SpeechRecognitionResult result) {
    lastWords = "${result.recognizedWords}";
    //print(lastWords);
    if (lastWords != '') {
      streamController.sink.add(lastWords);
    }
```

in the main Widget I implemented the stream listen in the OnLongPress function.

```
  onLongPress: () {
              Speech.startListening();
              Speech.streamController.stream.listen((data) {
                print("recibido: $data");
                setState(() {
                  text = data;
                });
              });
```

So far it's working well but I dont' know if this is the best way to handle this data transfer. If anyone knows a better way I would appreciate it, if this is a good way that would be the answer to this question.

// .-............... 2nd Update --------------------

That approach seems to work but I've realized that after a while I start getting the same data multiple times

> I/flutter (20460): listening I/flutter (20460): notListening I/flutter
> (20460): recibido: 123 I/chatty  (20460):
> uid=10166(com.example.speech_to_text_example) 1.ui identical 1 line 2
> I/flutter (20460): recibido: 123 I/chatty  (20460):
> uid=10166(com.example.speech_to_text_example) 1.ui identical 1 line
> I/flutter (20460): recibido: 123

for this particular example that doesn't matter but if I wanted to use that string for something like consuming a webservice thats a problem, I only want to get it once each time y start recording.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with my previous solution was that I was using a StreamController as broadcast and the listener was creating an instance every time I used the mic button, causing the redundant data. To solve that situation I created a stream controller in the Speech class, and then add a sink in the result listener.

```
StreamController<String> streamController = StreamController();

static resultListener(SpeechRecognitionResult result) {
    lastWords = "${result.recognizedWords}";
    //print(lastWords);
    if (lastWords != '') {
      streamController.sink.add(lastWords);
}
```

in the main Widget I called the streamController listener in the initState so the listener its instantiated only once which prevents the redundant data and the *"Stream has already been listened to"* error.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initSpeechState();    
    speech.streamController.stream.listen((event) {
      setState(() {
        text = event;
        print(text);
      });
 
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to notify parent class while lastwords is changing if you want to show it simultaneously. Moving your speech recognition class to widget  can make the trick. Create one variable at the top instead of lastwords and show in text widget.

```
 void startListening() async {
    await _speech.listen(
        onResult: (val) =>
    setState(() {
   _lastwords=val.recognizedWords;
      });
        cancelOnError: true,
        partialResults: false);
   
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Alperen baskaya, moving all methods to the main widget works but I want to keep UI and that logic separated.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to have an extra variable to store the future before assigning it to the text in setstate

```
onLongPress: () async  {
   var txt = await Speech.startListening();
   setState(() {
      text = txt;
   });
}
```

Comment: I tried that but I'm getting this error:

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building SubstringHighlight(dirty):
The method 'toLowerCase' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: toLowerCase()

The relevant error-causing widget was
SubstringHighlight
lib\page\home_page.dart:45